# Add a comment (description) to a trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

If I create a trigger with `CREATE TRIGGER` syntax in MySQL, how can I attach a comment to it, which describes it? I mean in the declaration or after it's the same to me.

I can't figure it out. With tables you add `COMMENT = 'Wonderful table with users inside';` at the end of the declaration. But how do you add comments to a trigger?

Comment: Triggers do not have this option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot attach a comment to a trigger.

You can however put comments in the trigger body.

If you type the *in body* comments like `/** comment **/`
You can extract these comments with the following query:

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING(b.body, b.start, (b.eind - b.start)) as comment 
FROM (
  SELECT
    a.body 
    ,locate('/**',a.body) as start
    ,locate('**/',a.body) as eind
  FROM (
    SELECT t.ACTION_STATEMENT as body FROM information_schema.triggers t 
    WHERE t.TRIGGER_NAME like %aname% 
  ) a
) b
```

Answer (score 4):

As a workaround, you may write a commented text inside a trigger's body, e.g. -

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
AFTER INSERT
ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  -- 'Wonderful trigger with insert inside';
  INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(NEW.id);
END
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put comment in mysql trigger in such way-

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger1
AFTER INSERT
ON table1
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  /*!99999 This is my comment , i will ignore at run time. */
  INSERT INTO table2 VALUES(NEW.id);
END
```

To prevent the “code” from being executed, you can just use a very high version number, such as 99999.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

`#"your comment"` it seems to work like `//"your comment"`

in other languages for example: C, C++, PHP etc.

Comment: Thanks @Dominik, but I think it makes no difference, since MySQL has no comment information associated to a trigger.

Comment: No problem @bluish, but i think that i have not understood You fully. You mean that there is no option to save comments to MySQL comments ?

Comment: yes, for tables you can add a comment to their metadata, but for triggers it is not supported.

Comment: Fortunately, I am using mysql workbench and my comments in trigger, were successfully transwered between databases and they are present in trigger code :)